# How can i get case ID in VF page from a custom object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller, angularjs

I have created a custom object **work_order__c** in this custom object i have created a **case field** as a **master-detail** to work_order__c. How can i get the case id in VF page for saving the workorder? I am using angularjs in VF page and its a new attempt.

please help.

```
<apex:page standardController="Work_Order__c" extensions="WorkOrderControllerExtension">

   <apex:inputField value="{!Work_Order__c.Case__c}" html-ng-model="workorder.Case__r.id"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is clear you are trying to get parent `Case__c` Id..

It is simple.. If you check `{!Work_Order__c.Case__c}` in VF this will display Case Id.

like

```
<apex:outputText value="{!Work_Order__c.Case__c}"/>
```

This will print Case Id

When we use `apex:inputField`. Salesforce create a lookup for us.. But in actual `{!Work_Order__c.Case__c}`  field contain the Case Id.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Work_Order__c.Case__c}" />
```

Let me know if you need any clarification

Comment: I tried the same earlier it gives me error.                                                   Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MALFORMED_ID, Case: id value of incorrect type: 00001006: [Case__c]                                                                                                            It is displaying case number as expected but while saving i need to save case id.

Comment: Yes, i am selecting case record from lookup. I am debugging from browser as it is client side code. I gives me case number.

Comment: @Ratan Wouldn't it be `{!Work_Order__r.Case__c}`?

Comment: @Poet `standardController="Work_Order__c"` so I believe `Case__c` is just a field on `Work_Order__c` object correct?

Comment: yes case is just a field(master-detail) in Work_Order__c.

Comment: @Ratan not yet.

Comment: i am using angularjs to bind case id to the lookup field html-ng-model="workorder.Case__c.id"

Comment: Ohhh..is it? So how can i bind the same using angularjs

Comment: I am using angularjs to save the data in Work_Order__c object for saving the case id i want to bind it with angularjs model, only than it will go the controller class. For binding the case id to angularjs model i need html-ng-model.

Comment: @Ratan Do i need to use javascript remoting to work with angularjs?

Comment: @Ratan Can you provide me with a sample of Javascript remoting to insert data in salesforce.. I am unable to find it on the net. All examples are of getting the data.

Comment: @Ratan I have changed my approach..I dont want to show lookup of case object in work order form. I just need a case id in my VF page so that i can save a particular work order with the associated case id. The challenge is i am using angularJs so unable to use visualforce tags like <apex:> in VF page how can i bind the case id to a particular angular model( within input html tag) to save the same.

Comment: @Ratan my main concern is how will i get the case id. I am able to get case number but i am not getting case id.

Comment: `00001006` looks like a `CaseNumber`, not a Case ID. In your schema, is `{!Work_Order__c.Case__c}` a lookup to case or a formula field to `CaseNumber`?

Comment: @Ejaz is crop1645 right or wrong?

Comment: @Ratan {!Work_Order__c.Case__c} a lookup to case and yes 00001006 is a CaseNumber

Comment: @Ratan Can you provide me with a sample as to how to pass Case Id on VF into a angular $scope.

Comment: @Ejaz do you know how to use angular factory read that first and try to implement

Comment: @Ratan i am getting the case id in url like "/apex/WorkOrderVF?RecordId=5004B000001OFX8" how can i use this value and pass it to $scope. Do i need factory for this or some other ways?

Comment: @Ejaz create factory https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services and pass the Id into your angular controller

Comment: @Ratan i have done it using visualforce remote objects. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: @Ejaz ohh finally you resolved it.. Thank god :-)